# How do you prove that the image of the real axis lies on a circle?

Tags: complex-numbers

The question is, Consider the map $$f(z) = (z + i)/(z - i)$$

Show that the image of the real
axis under z lies on a circle centred at the origin of the complex plane.

Basically, I've gotten up to this point: 
$$=((x^2 - 1) + 2xi)/(x^2 + 1)$$

And I'm stuck here. 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: I would write $z+i$ and $z-i$ in their exponential form, circles centered around the origin are very easy to write down in this form as well.

Comment: $$|f(z)-0|=\left|\frac{z+i}{z-i}-0\right|=\frac{|z+i|}{|z-i|}=\frac{\sqrt{z^2+1}}{\sqrt{z^2+1}}=1,\quad z\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

- any set $Z\subseteq \mathbb C$ lies on a circle centered at the origin if $\|z\|$ is constant for all $z\in\mathbb Z$.
- $\|z\|$ is constant if and only if $\|z\|^2$ is constant

Comment: does that mean I'm way off in what I did?

Comment: @Anjani No, it's a good first step in calculating $\|z\|^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you arrived at

$$\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}+\frac{2x}{x^2+1}i$$

If we identify this with a generic point on the plane $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ , we get

$$\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\,,\,\,\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\right)=:(a,b)$$

observe now that

$$a^2+b^2=\frac{x^4-2x^2+1+4x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}=\frac{(x^2+1)^2}{(x^2+1)^2}=1$$

and there you have your canonical circle: the unit one. You were very close indeed.

Answer (score 0):

First note that if $z$ is real, then $|z+i| = |z-i|$ (this is most easily seen geometrically), so $|f(z)|= 1$. Thus the image of every real number lies on the unit circle.

To show that it covers (almost) all of the unit circle, note that if $\theta$ is the angle of $z+i$, then $z-i$ has the angle $-\theta$, and therefore the angle of $f(z)$ is $2\theta$. As $z$ moves along the real axis, $\theta$ can get arbitrarily close to $\pi$ from below, and arbitrarily close to $0$ from above. In other words, $\theta \in (0, \pi)$, which means that the angle of $f(z)$ can be anywhere in $(0,2\pi)$, so the only value on the unit circle that isn't attained by $f$ is $1$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why (1, 0) isn't obtained?

Comment: @Anj Of course! $f(z) = 1$ means, by definition of $f$, that $\frac{z+i}{z-i} = 1$, which by definition of fractions means that $z+i = z-i$, which can be simplified to $2i = 0$. This can clearly never be the case.